# Error in multiplying a matrix by it's transpose: non-conformable arrays for matrix that should be comformable

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to multiply the transpose of a matrix by the original matrix.

```
B<-matrix(rep(c(10, -10,10), 15), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

I then transposed the matrix using `t(B)` function, giving me a 15 x 3 and 3 x 15 matrix, which I should be able to multiply as `B*t(B)` or `t(B)*B`. However, I get an error of 'Error in t(B) * B : non-conformable arrays'

Is this something I'm missing for this? I should be able to multiple either B*t(B) or t(B)*B since you would have a 3x3 matrix or 15 x 15 matrix for the answer.

Comment: `B %*% t(B)` is the matrix multiplication. `tcrossprod(B)` is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matrix multiplication, you should use `%*%` (`*` is for element-wise multiplication).

If you want a simple expression, you can try `crossprod` or `tcrossprod`, e.g.,

```
crossprod(B) # equivalent to t(B) %*% B
```

or

```
tcrossprod(B) # equivalent to B %*% t(B)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly it. Been a while since I dealt with matrix and forgot you have to treat them differently.